# How can I split a list in half in coq?

Tags: coq

It looks definitely simple task until I actually try to work on it. My method is to use twin pointers to avoid asking the length of the list ahead of time, but the difficulties come from the implication that I know for sure one list is "no emptier" than another. Specifically, in pseudo-coq:

```
Definition twin_ptr (heads, tail, rem : list nat) :=
  match tail, rem with
  | _, [] => (rev heads, tail)
  | _, [_] => (rev heads, tail)
  | t :: tl, _ :: _ :: rm => twin_ptr (t :: heads) tl rm
  end.

Definition split (l : list nat) := twin_ptr [] l l
```

But definitely it's not going to compile because the match cases are incomplete. However, the missing case by construction doesn't exist.

What's your way of implementing it?

Comment: Why don't you just return `([], [])` for the impossible case?

Comment: This is probably doable, but I am wondering how coq enforces such contract.

Comment: Actually there is a good reason to not dump out random results because it might make the proofs depending on this function much more difficult.

Comment: Actually, for `twin_ptr` taken alone that case is not impossible. It’s only when you use it in `split` that case becomes impossible. So you don’t have much choice with your implementation.

Comment: @AntonTrunov let's change my phrasing: how can i enforce `rem` is always in the right relation with `tail` such that it can be plugged in `split`? If twin pointers is not a good method for splitting lists, do you have a suggestion on how it's much better to implement in coq?

Comment: I’d probably prove a correctness lemma for the helper. That would probably give you a good answer for the missing case.

Comment: @AntonTrunov the reason why I am asking this question is to prove the correctness of a divide-and-conquer algo. in one step, if a list `l` is nonempty, I will need to split it in half, and since it's nonempty, the the second of the resulting tuple is also nonempty and I can extract the head of it. but i think it eventually goes to the same problem: how to encode contract inside of `Definition`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are not afraid of dependent types, you can add a proof that `rem` is shorter than `tail` as an argument of `twin_ptr`. Using `Program` to help manage these dependent types, this could give the following.

```
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.
Require Import Program.
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Omega.

Program Fixpoint twin_ptr
  (heads tail rem : list nat)
  (H:List.length rem <= List.length tail) :=
  match tail, rem with
  | a1, [] => (rev heads, tail)
  | a2, [a3] => (rev heads, tail)
  | t :: tl, _ :: _ :: rm => twin_ptr (t :: heads) tl rm _
  | [], _::_::_ => !
  end.
Next Obligation.
  simpl in H. omega.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
  simpl in H. omega.
Qed.

Definition split (l : list nat) := twin_ptr [] l l (le_n _).
```

The exclamation mark means that a branch is unreachable.

You can then prove lemmas about `twin_ptr` and deduce the properties of `split` from them. For example,

```
Lemma twin_ptr_correct : forall head tail rem H h t,
  twin_ptr head tail rem H = (h, t) ->
  h ++ t = rev head ++ tail.
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma split_correct : forall l h t,
  split l = (h, t) ->
  h ++ t = l.
Proof.
  intros. apply twin_ptr_correct in H. assumption.
Qed.
```

Personally, I dislike to use dependent types in functions, as resulting objects are more difficult to manipulate. Instead, I prefer defining total functions and give them the right hypotheses in the lemmas.

Comment: I am not sure if it's the right approach in coq specifically. in many algorithms, we have to break things into cases, and some are way more complicated than another. for those cases, I tend to extract them be their own function. it's going to be very boring to reason what the general cases mean when falling into a specific routine designed for specific input. it's ok that we encode dependent types in the type if such problem can be avoided.

Comment: There are two approaches here. Either you try to give a general meaning to your function written with only a special case in mind, and I agree that it can be a bit contrived. Or you just add to the lemmas the hypotheses that you would add to your function if you used dependent types, and the meaningless values returned by your function will never appear.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to maintain the invariant that the second list is bigger than the third. Here is a possible solution:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Div2.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Section Split.

Variable A : Type.

Fixpoint split_aux (hs ts l : list A) {struct l} : list A * list A :=
  match l with
  | []  => (rev hs, ts)
  | [_] => (rev hs, ts)
  | _ :: _ :: l' =>
    match ts with
    | []      => (rev hs, [])
    | h :: ts => split_aux (h :: hs) ts l'
    end
  end.

Lemma split_aux_spec hs ts l n :
  n = div2 (length l) ->
  split_aux hs ts l = (rev (rev (firstn n ts) ++ hs), skipn n ts).
Proof.
revert hs ts l.
induction n as [|n IH].
- intros hs ts [|x [|y l]]; easy.
- intros hs ts [|x [|y l]]; simpl; try easy.
  intros Hn.
  destruct ts as [|h ts]; try easy.
  rewrite IH; try congruence.
  now simpl; rewrite <- app_assoc.
Qed.

Definition split l := split_aux [] l l.

Lemma split_spec l :
  split l = (firstn (div2 (length l)) l, skipn (div2 (length l)) l).
Proof.
unfold split.
rewrite (split_aux_spec [] l l (div2 (length l))); trivial.
now rewrite app_nil_r, rev_involutive.
Qed.

End Split.
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest going via a more precise type? The main idea is to define a function splitting a `Vector.t` whose `nat` index has the shape `m + n` into a `Vector.t` of size `m` and one of size `n`.

```
Require Import Vector.

Definition split_vector : forall a m n,
  Vector.t a (m + n) -> (Vector.t a m * Vector.t a n).
Proof.
intros a m n; induction m; intro v.
- firstorder; constructor.
- destruct (IHm (tl v)) as [xs ys].
  firstorder; constructor; [exact (hd v)|assumption].
Defined.
```

Once you have this, you've reduced your problem to defining the `floor` and `ceil` of `n / 2` and proving that they sum to `n`.

```
Fixpoint div2_floor_ceil (n : nat) : (nat * nat) := match n with
  | O        => (O , O)
  | S O      => (O , S O)
  | S (S n') => let (p , q) := div2_floor_ceil n'
                in (S p, S q)
end.

Definition div2_floor (n : nat) := fst (div2_floor_ceil n).
Definition div2_ceil  (n : nat) := snd (div2_floor_ceil n).

Lemma plus_div2_floor_ceil : forall n, div2_floor n + div2_ceil n = n.
Proof.
refine
  (fix ih n := match n with
     | O => _
     | S O => _
     | S (S n') => _
   end); try reflexivity.
unfold div2_floor, div2_ceil in *; simpl.
destruct (div2_floor_ceil n') as [p q] eqn: eq.
simpl.
replace p with (div2_floor n') by (unfold div2_floor ; rewrite eq ; auto).
replace q with (div2_ceil n') by (unfold div2_ceil ; rewrite eq ; auto).
rewrite <- plus_n_Sm; do 2 f_equal.
apply ih.
Qed.
```

Indeed, you can then convert `length xs` into `ceil (length xs / 2) + floor (length xs / 2)` and use `split_vector` to get each part.

```
Definition split_list a (xs : list a) : (list a * list a).
Proof.
refine
  (let v      := of_list xs in
  let (p , q) := split_vector a (div2_floor _) (div2_ceil _) _ in
  (to_list p, to_list q)).
rewrite plus_div2_floor_ceil; exact v.
Defined.
```